# Looking to save file as UTF-8

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with french characters. When I open in it excel the french characters are gibberish, my work around is to open the file in Notepad and save encoding UTF-8. I can then open it in excel and the characters are good. I use this CSV file in a PowerShell script with excel macros to create users, the script works fine with the exception of names with french characters. Is there a way to solve this in PowerShell. I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
   Get-Content C:\sdk\userExport.csv | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 c:\sdk\newuserExport.csv
```

Comment: `Get-Content -Path 'C:\sdk\userExport.csv' -Encoding utf8`

Comment: It depends on how the CSV is actually encoded. Can you open it in Notepad++ and tell the encoding reported by Notepad++? (Alternatively enable status bar in Notepad to see the encoding, but it might be less reliable)

Comment: powershell 5.1 can't recognize utf8 no bom without help